# memcpy function issue when multiple times used

Tags: c

```
// Powered by Judge0
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>


typedef struct {
    char data[500];
    uint32_t len;
} payload;

void at_start(payload* payloadData)
{
    char p1[20] = "HI\r\n";
    memcpy(payloadData->data, p1, 4);
    payloadData->len = 4;
}

void at_net(payload* payloadData)
{
    char p1[20] = "HI CMDCMD\r\n";
    memcpy(payloadData->data, p1, 14);
    payloadData->len = 14;
}

int main(void) {

    payload* payloadData;
    at_start(payloadData);
    printf("Data : %s \n", payloadData->data);
    at_net(payloadData);
    printf("Data : %s \n", payloadData->data);
    at_start(payloadData);
    printf("Data : %s \n", payloadData->data);
    

    printf("Hello Judge0!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

can you help to figure out memcpy function issue when multiple times used and how to used data with dynamic length

issue when used data length was changed based on function.

issue is output got wrong.

```
Data : HI
 
Data : HI CMDCMD
 
Data : HI
MDCMD
```

last printf get extra \r\n

Comment: You never initialize `payloadData`.  Hence undefined behaviour.

Comment: this question not belongs to initialisation. issue is output got wrong.

Data : HI
 
Data : HI CMDCMD
 
Data : HI
MDCMD

last printf get extra \r\n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. *undefined behavior* is invoked by using `payloadData` without initialization
2. the `len` member is not read and data is simply printed until the end of string (null character `'\0'`)

Try this:

```c
int main(void) {
    /* initialize payloadData to a valid pointer */
    payload data;
    payload* payloadData = &data;
    at_start(payloadData);
    /* use %.*s to specify the length to print */
    printf("Data : %.*s \n", payloadData->len, payloadData->data);
    at_net(payloadData);
    printf("Data : %.*s \n", payloadData->len, payloadData->data);
    at_start(payloadData);
    printf("Data : %.*s \n", payloadData->len, payloadData->data);
    

    printf("Hello Judge0!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @MikeCAT. How to use pointer data with copy dynamic length of data?

Comment: Be aware this leaves your `data` without null-termination, making `data` unfit for the standard-libraries string-functions.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has two issues:

(1) data does not point to anything, you need to make it point to valid memory first (for example, using `malloc`). `memcpy` expects the memory-location of its source and destination to be valid - it does not return you a new memory-location, it works with the pointers you give them and does not modify them.

(2) When you copy a string in C, you need to make sure to also include the null-termination with the `\0`-character. You do not just want to copy 'H', 'I', '\r' and '\n' to the destination, but also '\0'. That is five bytes, not four.

Comment: How to use pointer data with copy dynamic length of data?

Comment: @DurgaSuthar that question is not clear, sorry. `data` needs to point to allocated heap or stack memory of at least `n` bytes if you want to `memcpy` n bytes to it. That is something you must guarantee as a programmer. If you do not have an upper bound for the value of n, you may want to look into `realloc`.